# want to display div on click of another div in yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I am new to Yii2 i want to display list of offers at left side when i clicked on offer it should displays details on right side.

this is my tradesmanOffer view page

```
 <?php
       foreach ($model as $offer) {
     ?>
     <div class="offer-row" data-id="<?=$offer->o_id?>">
     <div class="box">
     <div class="offer-col-7"> <div><b>NEW OFFER</b> from
       <?php
        if ($offer->c_id) {
          $contractor = Contractor::getoffername($offer->c_id);
          if (!empty($contractor)) {
             echo $contractor->name;
          }
        }
     ?></div>
```

this is my .js file:

```
$(function () {
  $(".offer-row").on("click", function (event) {
                  $(".offers").empty(); 
                  var tid = $(this).attr("data-id");
                alert(1);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "offer-details?t_id=" +tid,
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                         //alert(2);
                            $("#ajaxdiv").html('');
                            $("#ajaxdiv").html(data);
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
                });
```

this is my controller page as OfferController

```
public function actionOfferList() {
        if (Yii::$app->session->get('t_id') != "") {
            $model = new TradesmanOffer();
            $t_id = Yii::$app->session->get('t_id');
            $offers = $model->getOffers($t_id);
            return $this->render('tradesmanOffer', ['model' => $offers]);
        } else {
            return $this->redirect('../site/index');
        }
    }

    public function actionOfferDetails() {
        $t_id= $_GET['t_id'];
        $model = new TradesmanOffer();
        $offer = $model->getOffers($t_id);
        return $this->renderAjax('tradesmanOfferNew', ['model' => $offer]);
    }
```

this is my another view tradesmanOfferNew:

```
<div> <b>NEW OFFER</b> from
 <?php
  if ($offer->c_id) {
       $contractor = Contractor::getoffername($offer->c_id);
        if (!empty($contractor)) {
           echo $contractor->name;    
             }
  }
   ?>
```

and when i clicked on any offer and if refreshed browser it should same data on page.
how i achieve this?please help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `contentType: false` in your ajax call? Since you're getting some HTML from your call, you should set it to `html`